# Array formula to Extract Data on specific criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement, excel-indirect

Following is the formula that I am using:

`=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($A$1),IF(ROWS(A$2:A2)>$F$3, "", INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$J$4:$J$1000")=$D$3, ROW(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))-ROW(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$D$4"))+1),ROWS(A$2:A2)))),IF(ROWS(A$2:A2)>$F$3, "", IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,($A$1=(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$X$4:$X$1000")))*($D$3=(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$J$4:$J$1000"))),0)),"",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"),SMALL(IF((INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$J$4:$J$1000")=$D$3)*($A$1=(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$X$4:$X$1000"))), ROW(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$D$4:$D$1000"))-ROW(INDIRECT("'"&C$1&"'!$D$4"))+1),ROWS(A$2:A2)))))),"")`

- what the formula is doing is extracting the data on the basis of criteria mentioned in "$D$3"
- But it's only extracting it from one sheet for that i have used indirect formula and reference it with the sheet name
- I have also given it a sheet criteria
- what I want is that a formula to check whether criteria mentioned in "$D$3" is available in a particular sheet, if yes then extract all the items then go to next sheet check criteria there. if the items are available there as well extract them as well and repeat it till 31 sheets..
- What would be the VBA code if i want to extract list of data from multiple sheets on a separate sheet based on certain criteria

Thanks in advance

Additional Information:
Im mentioning as an answer but its not the solution to the problem, this what macro recorded

```
Sub ExtractValues()
'
' ExtractValues Macro
'

'
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(R1C1),IF(ROWS(R2C[-1]:R[-3]C[-1])>R3C6, """", INDEX(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$D$4:$D$1000""),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$J$4:$J$1000"")=R3C4, ROW(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$D$4:$D$1000""))-ROW(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$D$4""))+1),ROWS(R2C[-1]:R[-3]C[-1])))),IF(ROWS(R2C[-1]:R[-3]C[-1])>R3C6, """", IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,(R1C1=(INDIRECT(""'""&R1" & _
        "C[1]&""'!$X$4:$X$1000"")))*(R3C4=(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$J$4:$J$1000""))),0)),"""",INDEX(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$D$4:$D$1000""),SMALL(IF((INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$J$4:$J$1000"")=R3C4)*(R1C1=(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$X$4:$X$1000""))), ROW(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$D$4:$D$1000""))-ROW(INDIRECT(""'""&R1C[1]&""'!$D$4""))+1),ROWS(R2C[-1]:R[-3]C[-1])))))),""""" & _
        ")" & _
        ""
    Range("B5").Select

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then you need `VBA` macro to do that.

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: So, can you share a sample workbook with few sample data and explain logic and output. Upload the file into dropbox or google drive then share the downloadable link here.

Comment: try recording the process for one sheet with the macro recorder and then set up a loop. Post back with code and specific problem.